# Django: null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to add records via the code below:

```
  Post.objects.update_or_create(
  user=user,
  defaults={
      "title": external_post.get('title'),
      "body": external_post.get('body'),
      "seo": external_post.get('seo')
      }
  )
```

I've successfully migrated the model but I'm getting the error " null value in column "created_at" violates not-null constraint".

```
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced this same problem when I was using the `@transaction atomic` decorator in Django. Basically the reason why I faced the same error was that I was not using the default auto-increment ID in one of my models but rather I had specified a particular field as the primary key using `primary_key=True`

As a result my data contained two primary keys that were the same. This resulted in an 'update' operation rather than a 'create' operation in the database.

So, Django was trying to update an entry but the `created_at` field was missing hence the error.

I would suggest you do this instead:

```
post,created = Post.objects.update_or_create(
                   user=user,
                   defaults={
                       "title": external_post.get('title'),
                       "body": external_post.get('body'),
                       "seo": external_post.get('seo')
                    })
if created:
    # your code goes here
    #(this ensures that the code is executed only if an entry is getting created in the database)
```

You can read this for a better explaination: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17654